# Best practise/programme to use for "in situ" design i.e van wrap, shop decals

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, mockup

Have a new job where I am having to create "in situ" design i.e a quick mock-up of logos on vans or shop decals. I find myself fiddling quite a lot with perspective distort tool in illustrator or even trying to use and get familiar with the perspective grid tool in illustrator. Just wondering if there are any standard practises with creating design like this or even if I should be using photoshop? I chose illustrator because of familiarity and because I can scale things up and down as vectors and manipulate the shapes easily. I do know that mock-up templates use photoshop. Any youtube resources/tutorials would also be helpful

Comment: whatabout using an actual 3D program?

Comment: You can place AI files as Smart Objects in Photoshop, and apply perspective transforms non-destructively, so yes, that's a feasible way to make mock-ups.

Answer (score 0):

I used Illustrator for over 10  years to mock up for signs, garments .
I used to have customers bring in the their cars and I was taping a ruler on each side before taking a picture so I can scale them accurately, One of my major problem that I encountered was when I was making a file to cut a decal for a windshield so it will follow the curvature at the top, and I end up tracing the curvature on the paper so I can make an accurate file to cut the decal.